# Try loop is showing change but not applying it

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.7

(Using Python 3) I am working with multiple dictionaries within a dictionary, and am trying to run a try except loop to replace all number in the individual dictionaries with floats.

I'm running something like this,

```
for index, value in enumerate(dictionary):
    for stats in value:
        try:
            stats = float(stats)
            print(stats)
        except:
            print(stats)
```

and it's physically showing me the changes, but not applying them. As in, the line of code returns what I need changed in the dictionaries, but when I run the full dictionary afterwards, the numbers are still strings.

Anyone have any ideas for this one?

Comment: U didn't reassign it ?

Comment: try/execpt is not a loop...

Comment: `stats = float(stats)` This does not save the converted value back to the dictionary.  It just assigns a new value to the local variable `stats`, which is then lost because you didn't save it anywhere.

Comment: Can you show an example dictionary? Why do you need the index?

Comment: Add example dictionary and expected output, too.

Answer (score 0):

without knowing exactly what your dictionary looks like, I had to make some assumptions. The issue you were having is that you were not directly modifying the value in the dict, but instead creating a new instance and modifying that.

```
my_dict = {1:["1", "2", "3"], 2:["4", "5", "6"]} #I assume your dict looks similar to this?

my_dict = {i:[float(x) for x in my_dict[i]] for i in my_dict} #using list comprehension to modify each value
```

Method 2 using a for loop

```
for i in my_dict:
    for index, v in enumerate(my_dict[i]):
        my_dict[i][index] = float(my_dict[i][index])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to `stats` doesn't modify `value`.

All you need to assign to `value` is the index, so you could use `enumerate` like this:

```
d = {0: ['0', 'a'], 1: ['1', 'b']}  # I assume your dict is like this

for value in d.values():
    for i, stats in enumerate(value):
        try:
            value[i] = float(stats)
        except ValueError:
            pass

print(d)  # -> {0: [0.0, 'a'], 1: [1.0, 'b']}
```

BTW a bare `except` is really bad practice (see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)). I just need to catch `ValueError` in this example, but you might need to catch `TypeError` as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked like a charm. Also, thanks for the BTW advice. I am pretty new to coding.